# How to make a Rails application global?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Currently, I am working on a website using Ruby on Rails, the website has many small applications for example full calendar, chat session, user verification etc. I created a new application recently called Todo list which acts as a reminder very simple. It currently has its own page `my_link/todo_lists`.

How do I make it in such a way that instead of just appearing on the `#index` page it shows up everywhere on the website? I have tried to `require 'todo_lists'` but I get the error:

```
"cannot load such file -- todo_lists"
```

I tried copying all the files into the layouts folder (a feeble attempt). That gives me:

```
"Missing templates ....."
```

I tried to render partial (Not sure how it works)

Again "Missing templates" or "no_load_to_path" error

If possible I want it to appear like that of a Facebook chat bar, the very least is call the same thing but on a different page.

Comment: I think you're on the right path with shared partials

Comment: You could create a mountable [`Rails::Engine`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/engines.html) which is essentially a rails application that can be plugged in to another rails application. I find this makes it easier to manage the code rather than a huge monolith. It does take a bit more setup however.

Comment: Thank you guys I will read up both methods! At least now there is a way. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an ERB partial inside `layouts/_sidebar.html.erb` and then in your `application.html.erb` you render the partial with:

```
  <%= render 'layouts/sidebar' %>
```

This will make it appear in all the application (assuming you have only one main layout)

Comment: I took your advice and used the sidebar instead. It works great! If you don't mind me asking. I have used ajax to make my Todo_List pop out (running in the background) instead of having to navigate to a different page. When I try to render in the sidebar using

<% content_for(:sidebar) do %>
  <% render :partial => "layouts/sidebar" %>
<% end %>

on the page I want.

I have now encountered the problem that it won't do that on my sidebar as it did on the index page. Basically, I can create but I cannot edit or show. It shows a grey screen.